# How to create a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please help me, how to filter words in SQL using a function?

I'm having a hard time if I explain it so I'm giving example:

```
ID       |       WebsiteName      |
-----------------------------------
1        |      www.yahoo.com     |
2        |      www.google.com    |
3        |      www.youtube.com   |
```

What I want is, how to get the name of the website. I want to select the record with an output like this. How to remove the 'www.' and '.com' in the record.

```
ID      |      WebsiteName
--------------------------    
1       |        yahoo
```

thanks for the help. :D

Comment: You haven't explained adequately. Do you want to do this just during a `SELECT`, or as a computed column? Do you wish to just to extract a domain name at one level (how would you like `www.example.co.uk` to be treated?)?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

How about this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripWWWandCom (@input VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Work VARCHAR(250)

    SET @Work = @Input

    SET @Work = REPLACE(@Work, 'www.', '')
    SET @Work = REPLACE(@Work, '.com', '')

    RETURN @work
END
```

and then use:

```
SELECT ID, dbo.StripWWWandCom (WebsiteName)
FROM dbo.YourTable .....
```

Of course, this is **severely limited** in that it will only strip `www.` at the beginning and `.com` at the end - nothing else (so it won't work on other host machine names like `smtp.yahoo.com` and other internet domains such as `.org`, `.edu`, `.de` and etc.)

Comment: You could use the `STUFF` and `CHARINDEX` like this: 

`SET @Work = STUFF(@Work, CHARINDEX('www.', @Work), LEN('www.'), '')`

Answer (score 13):

This one get everything between the "." characters.  Please note this won't work for more complex URLs like "www.somesite.co.uk"  Ideally the function would check for how many instances of the "." character and choose the substring accordingly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetURL (@URL VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Work VARCHAR(250)

    SET @Work = @URL

    SET @Work = SUBSTRING(@work, CHARINDEX('.', @work) + 1, LEN(@work))   
    SET @Work = SUBSTRING(@work, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @work))

    --Alternate:
    --SET @Work = SUBSTRING(@work, CHARINDEX('.', @work) + 1, CHARINDEX('.', @work) + 1)   

    RETURN @work
END
```

Answer (score 9):

I can give a small hack, you can use T-SQL function. Try this:

```
SELECT ID, PARSENAME(WebsiteName, 2)
FROM dbo.YourTable .....
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use stuff in place of replace for avoiding the bug that Hamlet Hakobyan has mentioned

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripWWWandCom (@input VARCHAR(250)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(250) 
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @Work VARCHAR(250)
   SET @Work = @Input

   --SET @Work = REPLACE(@Work, 'www.', '')
   SET @Work = Stuff(@Work,1,4, '')
   SET @Work = REPLACE(@Work, '.com', '')

   RETURN @work 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for most of the website names :

`SELECT ID, REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(WebsiteName), 2)) FROM dbo.YourTable .....`