# How to capture duplicate values and show message box while reading from database?

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, csla, executereader

I've a DataGrid which uses a list object. I would like to prevent users from entering duplicate values into database.

My stored procedure already prevents duplicate data from entering into database but I would like to show a more descriptive message to the users explaining they can't enter duplicate values.

Below is my code where I'm inserting values via Stored Procedure:

```
using (var cn = ConnectionManager<SqlConnection>.GetManager(Database))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Save", cn.Connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableId", ReadProperty(TableIdProperty));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q1", ReadProperty(Q1Property).ToUpper());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q2", ReadProperty(Q2Property));

                using (var dr = new SafeDataReader(cmd.ExecuteReader()))
                {
                    //Would like to capture duplicates here if a record already exists with same Q1 and Q2 values 
                    if (dr.Read())
                        LoadProperties(dr);
                    else
                        dr.NextResult(); // sproc error happens here
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you share the code of stored procedure? How it is preventing duplicate values? Does it raise any error if there are duplicate values?

Comment: It does raise an Application Error and 'rolls back' the insert.

Comment: I added sproc code where it's  raising error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right you have an Application where users can Insert new rows and you want to prevent duplicated entries.

If this is right you could add a Database Function that returns an ErrorCode and you could call this function using `SqlCommand` from your code.

Comment: Yeah you're right. When they enter new rows I want to prevent duplicate entries. Could you please assist me with SqlCommand?

Comment: You mean how to execute?

Comment: Yeah I meant I didn't understand how I'd write a database function that you recommended.

Comment: See at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550486/how-to-create-a-function-in-sql-server for how to create an `function` in the database. You can write the same code you have in your stored procedure to check for duplicate entries

Comment: Just an suggestion. A good approach for not allowing double entries in a table is to create an unique index that contains the specific column.