# Create function with conditional calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to create a function with a conditional calculation before the `RETURN` statement, but SSMS states that there is an incorrect syntax near `'BEGIN  IF @param2 IS NULL'` and I can't figure out what is wrong with this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConditionalFunction
(
    @input1 VARCHAR(20),
    @input2 VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS BEGIN
    IF @input2 IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @input2 = field
        FROM table1
        WHERE filter = @input1
    END

    RETURN
    (
        SELECT field1, field2
        FROM table2
        WHERE filter1 = @input1
        AND filter2 = @input2
    )
END
```

My goal is to be able to call it either

```
ConditionalFunction('Foo',NULL)
```

or

```
ConditionalFunction('Foo','Bar')
```

In a way that the first call will make it detect a default value for `@input2` based on `@input1`.

I wrote this code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550528/7831383).
This is SQL Server 13. Could you please tell me if there is anything I can do to make it compile?

---

N.B: I obviously replaced real names with generics, but the code structure remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but change the `@Data` table types to your data types:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConditionalFunction
(
    @input1 VARCHAR(20),
    @input2 VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS @Data TABLE
(
    field1 VARCHAR(12)
   ,field2 VARCHAR(12)
)
AS 
BEGIN

    IF @input2 IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @input2 = field
        FROM table1
        WHERE filter = @input1
    END

    INSERT INTO @Data
    SELECT field1, field2
    FROM table2
    WHERE filter1 = @input1
    AND filter2 = @input2


    RETURN;
END
```

There are several types of functions in SQL:

- scalar return only one value
- inline - returns a table (it is like view with parameters)
- table-valued - returns a table

Your syntax looks like you need a inline function, but should contain only one `SELECT` statement returning the data. So, you need to create a table-valued function.